# Does save_kable prevent the table from being shown in rendered R Markdown document?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

When I knit the R Markdown document, my tables (created in kableExtra) show up if I do not save them (using save_kable [saving to PDF]). However if I save them, the tables are no longer rendered and shown in the R Markdown document. Is there a way to stop this from happening?